# Scrape data using R when div class is different for the same attribute

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a full description from a website with a div class as such:

[image]

This div class changes for data that would go in the same column. I am using the following r code for other div classes that do not change:

```
#get the beer IBU
num_ibu <- html_nodes(webpage, ".ibu")
num_ibu <- as.character(html_text(num_ibu))
```

My question is how do I modify this code to find a div class *like* '.desc-full'? I have tried `full_desc <- html_nodes(webpage, ".desc-full*")` only to receive the following error:

```
Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : 
  Expected selector, got <DELIM '*' at 11>
```

I seem to be having a difficult time finding a `like` command that works in `html_nodes`. Is this a case where I should use regex? That feels like overkill.

Comment: Can we get the URL?

Comment: https://untappd.com/beer/top_rated?country_id=86   I am using this data for... ahem... personal research :)

Comment: And you're trying to extract the description of the beers correct?

Comment: Yes, with the div class of `desc-full-####`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webpage <- "https://untappd.com/beer/top_rated?country_id=86"

sess <- html_session(webpage)
all_desc_nodes <- html_nodes(sess, ".desc")
full_desc_nodes <- all_desc[grep("desc-full", all_desc_nodes)]
full_desc_text <- html_text(full_desc_nodes)
```

Comment: It looks like this will work! So you gather them all together in a variable, then grep that variable. Makes sense! I did have to change this line" `all_desc[grep("desc-full", all_desc)]` to this: `all_desc_nodes[grep("desc-full", all_desc_nodes)]`. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for catching the typo. so funny, not the first time a stackoverflow search led me back to my own years-old answer.